# Create a position using workday SOAP create position endpoint

Tags: soap, soapui, workday-api

The requirement is to send a request to workday create position endpoint and create a position through the API.  according to workday community, Request body has certain fields to be filled. https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/Recruiting/v31.2/Create_Position.html 
could anyone help me with filing the request body?

Comment: You would need to work with the Workday team that you are trying to create positions for to know which fields they need to be filled out. Just because the field isn't required, doesn't mean it isn't needed.

Comment: @WyattShipman thanks. if I capture values for a particular position, for example, take the driver. If I capture values for that and send those captured values to the relevant endpoint, would it work? Assume I have required credentials.

Comment: There are some things within Workday to consider, such as are you hiring into a Supervisory Organization that has a Job Management vs a Position Management Model? Does the Supervisory org have Default/Allowed values for Cost Centers or Company that you need to use. Off of the top of my head, I can't remember the exact process if you need to create a requisition to hire onto.